# Why the existence of gunzip?

Tags: gzip

What are the reasons (historical, compatibility issues ..) for the existence of  `gunzip` despite `gzip` offers the same (and extended) functionality?

I checked `/bin/gzip` and `/bin/gunzip` and they are separated executables. 
Why not an unique executable and two symlinks?

Comment: I'd say it's mostly for historic reasons.  Some ~25 years ago by far the most popular archiver was `pkzip`, and it had a `pkunzip` counterpart.  It was followed by a flurry of other archives following the same naming scheme.  In the world of commercial UNIX there was a `compress` and an `uncompress`.  I think `rar` (or maybe `arj`?  I can't remember) was the first major archiver that used the same executable for both operations.

Comment: Rahul Dhesi's `zoo`, from 1986, had addition and extraction in one program.

Comment: Interesting question. Probably the only way to find out for sure is to find the reasons through an extensive search of old Usenet articles or e-mails. I suspect that @lcd047 is correct. gzip uses the same Lempel-Ziv algorithm that pkzip used so I guess they decided that its a clone of pkzip. I never think of it as a clone of pkzip but when you read the gzip man page that connection cannot be ignored.

Comment: Hmm, the case of `zoo` is interesting.  It was indeed popular on BBSes and the like, but for whatever reasons I don't think it was nearly as influential al `pkzip`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, it was common for compressors to have symmetric decompressors, for one simple reason: when you start distributing files compressed with a new compression program, you want recipients to be able to easily decompress them. Generally speaking, when they're separate, the decompression program is simpler and smaller than the compression program, which makes it easier to transfer (think of transmission speeds and storage capacity thirty years ago), and easier to port to new systems too.

I can't find the original releases of `gzip` so I don't know if that applied in this particular case; the oldest version I've found, 1.2.4, released in 1993, already used a single binary for `gzip` and `gunzip`. Note that current versions still support this; `gunzip` is just a wrapper shell script.